# Encapsulating a variable per instance in Angular 4

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I have an application, where a `ProductComponent` is repeated multiple times as a list. Within this `ProductComponent`, there is a public `boolean` local variable  called `this.showPriceLoadingText`.
However when this variable is updated within an instance, all other instances within the list are updated.
I thought es6 encapsulated variables within the instance/scope it resides in, evidently not.

How could I make this variable behave independently?

```
class ProductComponent(){

 public showBasketLoadingText: boolean;
 public addingToBasketText: string = "";

 constructor() {
    this.showBasketLoadingText = false;
    this.addingToBasketText = environment.configurations.uiConfig.addingToBasketText;
 }

QuickAddtoCart(product: Product) {

    this.showBasketLoadingText = true;

    //DO STUFF

    let _self = this;
    setTimeout(function(){
        _self.showBasketLoadingText = false;
    }, 1000);
  }

}
```

HTML:

```
<span *ngIf="(!this.showBasketLoadingText)"><i class="fa fa-cart-arrow-down" aria-hidden="true"></i> Add to basket</span>
<span *ngIf="(this.showBasketLoadingText)">{{ addingToBasketText }}</span>
```

Comment: The variable is independent by default. You'll need to show your code for others to be able to tell why this is not the case in your application.

Comment: Question has been updated, I have taken off all other code in attempt to simplify the code

Comment: variables ARE definitely encapsulated / independent by default. if you put that what you have there in a plunkr, it will work fine. Something else in your code is broken.

Comment: Ive now worked it out... i discovered that the component actually only a product list as opposed to a single product. Apologies for wasting your time

Comment: @vicgoyso : you can post this as an answer to your own question, it might help some other person facing the same issue

Comment: cheers, done. Cant believe I missed something so obvious, my excuse its friday, lol.

Answer (score 0):

You should use this way (arrow notation) to preserve `this`:

```
setTimeout(() => {this.showBasketLoadingText = false;}, 1000);
```

[more info here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions)

> An arrow function does not have its own this; the this value of the
>   enclosing execution context is used.

Comment: Hi Pac0...
Yes i did think of that, hence... let _self = this; _self.showBasketLoadingText = false;

Comment: Ive now worked it out... i discovered that the component actually only a product list as opposed to a single product. Apologies for wasting your time

Answer (score 0):

Ive now worked it out... i discovered that the component actually only a product list as opposed to a single product. Apologies for wasting your time